# Python - Error output with print function

Tags: python, printing

I'm new to Python.
I want to print elements in the list without duplicate in a specific format: {"id": value}. 
Here is my code.

```
d =['l','o','u','l','b','l','a']

for item in range(0,len(d)):
  prev=item-1
  if item==0:
    print("  {\"id\": \"" + (d[item]) + "\"} ,") 
    continue
  if (d[item]==d[prev])or(d[item] in d[:prev]):
    continue
  else:
    print("  {\"id\": \"" + (d[item]) + "\"}"),
    if (item==(len(d))): #if last element, print  ".", else print ","
        print(".\n"),
    else:
        print(",\n"),
```

The result should be:

```
  {"id": "l"} ,
  {"id": "o"} ,
  {"id": "u"} ,
  {"id": "b"} ,
  {"id": "a"} .
```

But the output is:

```
  {"id": "l"} ,
  {"id": "o"} ,
  {"id": "u"} ,
  {"id": "b"} ,
  {"id": "a"} ,
```

My code works well until the last line. It ends with "," instead of ".". 
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if (item==len(d)-1):`

The last item has index len(d)-1.

Btw, there is way easier approaches to remove duplicates in a list using set():

`list(set(['a', 'a', 'b']))` will return `['a','b']`)

Warning: If you use `set()` you will loose the order of the items. If you want to keep the order, see [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order).

Comment: thanks. it works. but if I edit the list to d =['l','o','u','l','b','l'], it doesn't work. is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: This is because you do not enter the `else` clause. ` if d[item]==d[prev])or(d[item] in d[:prev]):` returns true because you have already seen 'l'.

Comment: Do we have any other ways? Because of some further problems, the list should be kept originally, not remove any elements inside.

Comment: Solved.

I create a new list without no duplicate + preserving order.
Then everything left is easy to solve.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In python the range(0, N) function returns numbers from 0 - N-1.
In your case you have used N = len(d), so you should change the if statement accordingly. 
Try:

```
if (item==(len(d)-1)): #if last element, print  ".", else print ","
    print(".\n")
```

Instead.

The full running code should look like this:

```
d =['l','o','u','l','b','l','a']
for item_id, item in enumerate(set(d)):
  if item_id != (len(d) - 1):
    print("  {\"id\": \"" + item + "\"} ,") 
  else:
    print("  {\"id\": \"" + item + "\"} .")
```

Comment: thanks. it works. but if I edit the list to d =['l','o','u','l','b','l'], it doesn't work. is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: I edited my response to contain a full working version

Comment: p.s. it would be nice of you to vote up those who answered your question and accept an answer.

Comment: @Roy, may be a typo, but you did use `set` twice. Once before loop and once in enumerate

Comment: Excuse me, can you recheck your code, it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

`if (item==(len(d)))` code will never hit this block, because
item can only go upto `len(d)-1`

```
d =['l','o','u','l','b','l','a']

for item in range(0,len(d)):
  prev=item-1
  if item==0:
    print("  {\"id\": \"" + (d[item]) + "\"} ,") 
    continue
  if (d[item]==d[prev])or(d[item] in d[:prev]):
    continue
  else:
    print("  {\"id\": \"" + (d[item]) + "\"}"),
    if (item!=(len(d))-1): #if last element, print  ".", else print ","
        print(",\n"),
print(".\n")
```

Using sets:

```
d =['l','o','u','l','b','l','a']
d = list(set(d))
for item in range(0,len(d)):
    print("  {\"id\": \"" + (d[item]) + "\"}"),
    if (item!=(len(d))-1): #if last element, print  ".", else print ","
        print(",\n"),
print(".\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
But if I edit the list to d =['l','o','u','l','b','l'], it doesn't work. Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: This won't work  because you have `  if (d[item]==d[prev])or(d[item] in d[:prev]): continue` this will skip this check.

Comment: I edited your code for the question you asked, but using python set as others pointed out is a good way to reduce the code size.

Comment: Excuse me, can you recheck your code? it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

As `range` is exclusive, `range(0,len(d))` will have values from 0 to len(d) - 1. So, your if statement should be -

```
if item == (len(d) - 1):
    print(".\n")
```

If the last element in the list is a duplicate it is better to create a set. Try the following -

```
d = {'l','o','u','l','b','l'}

for i, e in enumerate(d):
    print("  {\"id\": \"" + (e) + "\"}"),
    if i == len(d) - 1:
        print(".\n")
    else:
        print(",\n")
```

Here, `d = {'l','o','u','l','b','l'}` creates a set which removes duplicate elements. Then you can just simply iterate over it

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
But if I edit the list to d =['l','o','u','l','b','l'], it doesn't work. Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: Because last element `l` is a duplicate. Best solution is to make a set and iterate over it

Comment: The output is right but not in order. Can we still keep the order of the list?